# How to ensure sending only once with trigger

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have Automatically send emails by script. But I only want to sent automatically when cell C: C is "done"
And if there is a [K] number 1 in cell 12, the number 1 is automatically written when the e-mail is sent. But an auto-trigger sends emails always.

What the table looks like:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jgAdvV1UcAnh9qw3QQU9q_8MVSIyZmrukhOVxz3CJUA/edit#gid=0

```
// This constant is written in column L for rows for which an email
// has been sent successfully.
var EMAIL_SENT = '1';

/**
 * Sends non-duplicate emails with data from the current spreadsheet.
 */
function sendEmails2() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var startRow = 2; // First row of data to process
  var numRows = 1; // Number of rows to process
  // Fetch the range of cells A2:B3
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 3); //
  // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  var text = sheet.getRange("D2").getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
    var row = data[i];
    var message = row [2]; // Third column
    var emailSent = row[3]; // Fourth column
    if (emailSent != EMAIL_SENT) { // Prevents sending duplicates
      var subject = 'Text is'+ text +'';


      MailApp.sendEmail('example@gmail.com', subject, message);
      sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 12).setValue(EMAIL_SENT);//sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 12).setValue(EMAIL_SENT)
      // Make sure the cell is updated right away in case the script is interrupted
      SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    }
  }
}
```

To send an email, it will only search cell D for changed states to "done"

Comment: Since i starts at `0` you should increment by one: `sheet.getRange(startRow + i + 1, 12).setValue(EMAIL_SENT);`. Additionally keep in mind that your script is checking for a `string` with value `1`. When you manually enter `1` in a cell, this would typically be a number value instead of a string.

Comment: Be aware that when you provide your spreadsheet, the attached script is also viewable. Make sure that it does not contain personal data.

Answer (score 0):

To check either the value in column C is "done", compelement your `if` statement with the criteria `state == "done"`:

```
    ...
    var emailSent = row[11];// twelfth column
    var state = row[3]; // Fourth column
    if (state == "done"&&emailSent!=EMAIL_SENT) { 
      var subject = 'Upozornění změna stavu na '+ text +'';
      MailApp.sendEmail('example@gmail.com', subject, message);
      sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 12).setValue(EMAIL_SENT);
      SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    }
   ...
```

Please also incorporate the corrections offered by Casper in his comment:

`var EMAIL_SENT = 1;` and `var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 12);`

Also, keep in mind that Apps Script can detect the [last row and column](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getlastrow), which would allow you to rewrite your code more elegantly:

```
var numRows=sheet.getLastRow()-startRow+1;
var startColumn=1;
var numColumns=sheet.getLastColumn()-startColumn+1
var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, startColumn, numRows, numColumns);
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like you put much effort into preparing this question.

```
var EMAIL_SENT = '1';
function sendEmails2() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var startRow = 2;
  var numRows = 1; //This should be changed...perhaps to sheet.getLastRow()-startRow+1
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 3); //
  var data=dataRange.getValues();
  var text=sheet.getRange("D2").getValues();//This should be getValue() and column D in your sheet is State so this is probably wrong
  for (var i=0;i<data.length;++i) {
    var row = data[i];
    var message = row [2];//This is your data insert column so this is not your message
    var emailSent = row[3];//This is not column12 as it is in your spreadsheet so that's wrong 
    if (emailSent != EMAIL_SENT) { //this does not work as it stands now
      var subject = 'Text is'+ text +''; //This text is not defined on your spreadsheet
      MailApp.sendEmail('example@gmail.com', subject, message);//There is no subject nor any intelligent message
      sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 12).setValue(EMAIL_SENT);
    }
  }
}
```